# Why is Showdown not working in my Meteor project?

Tags: javascript, meteor, markdown, showdown

I'm learning Meteor and I can't get Showdown to work in my templates.

These tags:

```
{{#markdown}}{{desc}}{{/markdown}}
```

Result in this error:

```
Exception in queued task: Error: Can't find template, helper or data context key: markdown
```

I ran "meteor list --using" and Showdown is listed as installed. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Where is desc defined?

Comment: Markdown should be defined before calling desc

Comment: desc is in a collection that I've been working with. It displays fine if it's not inside the markdown tags -- it only contains a few lines separated by double line breaks and no special markdown characters. I just tried removing it from the template but I still got the error.

Comment: The meteor documentation says this about Showdown: "It's easy: just put your markdown inside {{#markdown}} ... {{/markdown}} tags." So, my assumption is that adding the package is all I need to define the tag. Am I missing something?

Comment: This question should be plainly removed.

Comment: I think the answer could have value, since I learned that Meteor was reporting that it had installed the package but actually hadn't. That might help others with troubleshooting in the future should they run into a similar situation.

That value is slightly obscured by the comments on the answer, which were well-intentioned but off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Even though Showdown was being listed when I ran "meteor list --using" it was not in .meteor/packages for some reason. I added it manually and now the markdown is working perfectly.

Comment: you can use `meteor add <package>` to add meteor optional packages.

Comment: Yes, that is how I added Showdown. But it wasn't working, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: I'm on latest: 0.8.1.3